# RunTest or RunBlocing Test is not importing in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, coroutine

Unresolved reference: runTest
Unresolved reference: test
or
Unresolved reference: runBlockingTest

tried different depedencies

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That was an importing issue that I state here. it happens because of gradle problem in my case

Answer (score 1):

This can be the fix.

Replace:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4'
```

With:

```
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4'
```